# Add key and value of one list of dictionaries to another list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have two python lists of dictionaries.

One is a keylist with multiple ids and date when updated.

Other list is about persons, in list of persons there is person_id which corresponds with p_id in the keylist. I want to add the fam_id from keylist to persons dictionary.

```
keylist = [{'p_id':'001','fam_id':'FAM98','update':'2021-07-29'},
           {'p_id':'002','fam_id':'FAM1978','update':'2021-07-29'},
           {'p_id':'003','fam_id':'FAM1978','update':'2021-07-29'}]

persons = [{'person_id':'001','dob':'01-20-1997','mom_id':'34','color':'brown'},
           {'person_id':'002','dob':'12-05-2001','mom_id':'003', 'color':'black'},
           {'person_id':'003','dob':'01-02-1977','mom_id':'320', 'color':'brown'}]
```

I would like to get:

```
persons = [{'person_id':'001','dob':'01-20-1997','mom_id':'34','color':'brown','fam_id':'FAM98'},
           {'person_id':'002','dob':'12-05-2001','mom_id':'003','color':'black','fam_id':'FAM1978'},
           {'person_id':'003','dob':'01-02-1977','mom_id':'320','color':'brown','fam_id':'FAM1978'}]
```

I don't know how to get this.
What I tried was this (but I don't know how to get lcreate from keylist):

```
lcreate = {'001': 'FAM98', '002': 'FAM1978', '003': 'FAM1978'}
for dic in persons: dic["fam_id"] = lcreate[dic["person_id"]]
```

How can I get one dict(lcreate) from list of dict (keylist)?

Comment: In your last code block, you have `lcreate= {'001': ''FAM98',...` is the quote mark in front of FAM98 intentionally duplicated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over both lists, and update `persons` dictionaries when those keys match.

```
keylist=[{'p_id':'001','fam_id':'FAM98','update':'2021-07-29'},{'p_id':'002','fam_id':'FAM1978','update':'2021-07-29'},{'p_id':'003','fam_id':'FAM1978','update':'2021-07-29'}]
persons=[{'person_id':'001','dob':'01-20-1997','mom_id':'34', 'color':'brown'},{'person_id':'002','dob':'12-05-2001','mom_id':'003', 'color':'black'},{'person_id':'003','dob':'01-02-1977','mom_id':'320', 'color':'brown'}]
for x in persons:
    for y in keylist:
        if x['person_id'] == y['p_id']:
            x['fam_id'] = y['fam_id']
```

Result

```
>>> persons
[{'person_id': '001', 'dob': '01-20-1997', 'mom_id': '34', 'color': 'brown', 'fam_id': 'FAM98'},
 {'person_id': '002', 'dob': '12-05-2001', 'mom_id': '003', 'color': 'black', 'fam_id': 'FAM1978'},
 {'person_id': '003', 'dob': '01-02-1977', 'mom_id': '320', 'color': 'brown', 'fam_id': 'FAM1978'}]
```